# Sort Method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am new to VBA and having a hard time figuring out this code.I am doing a course online and i followed the same steps but somehow i'm getting an error.I recently installed Excel 2013 and dont know if thats the issue.I tried putting .Range("A4") but that gives me an error of **"Invalid or Unqualified Reference"**

```
Sub DivisionSort()
'
' Sort List by Division Ascending
'

'
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub

Sub CategorySort()
'
' Sort List by Category Ascending
'

'
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("B4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub

Sub TotalSort()
'
' Sort List by Total Sales Ascending
'

'
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("F4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub


Public Sub SortList()
    Dim userinput As String
    userinput = InputBox("1=Sort by Division, 2=Sort by Category,3=Sort by Total")
    If userinput = "1" Then
    DivisionSort
    ElseIf userinput = "2" Then
    CategorySort
    ElseIf userinput = "3" Then
    TotalSort

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Selection.Range("A4")

Comment: Still not working.Its giving the same error :(

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, but I get "Sort method of Range class failed" error if only one cell is selected and works if more than one cell is selected.

Comment: If the `Selection` doesn't contain the specified key range, the sort method will fail

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid use of 'Selection'. Try instead a full reference:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1").Sort
```

Comment: While accurate, you can't really sort a range of one cell :P